# Re-Enumerating all Serial devices in java using Javax.comm

Tags: java, serial-port, enumeration, javax.comm

Here is the code that I am implementing for Enumeration of devices. I am able to detect and display all the Serial devices connected.But suppose I connected another device and then try to recall this function, It is always showing the devices that are connected during first run of the code.

Code Snipet:

```
public void Listports() {

    Enumeration ports = null;
    ports  = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;

    {
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {

             portId = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();

            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL){                    

                System.out.println(portId.getName());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. For Example, in the first Call of the function , COM1 and COM3 are displayed.

Now suppose,  a Serial Device connected is loaded on COM27. So If we re-run the code it is displaying only COM1 and COM3, and  no COM27.

Another scenario, Before my first run of the code a Serial device is loade on COM27. Now on first run it shows COM1,COM3,COM27. Now remove the COM27 device and re-run the above piece of code, It still shows COM27 is connected.

Any Help in this regard is greatly Appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: you didnt post any code that actually tests if a port is connected, you just enumate the available ports

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail, I guess (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) is actually testing if a serial device is connected, Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

[Comm port API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html)

you just get a list op comm ports, you can then for example try if the port is owned aka used by some application with isCurrentlyOwned()

Basicly just iterating a list doesnt tell you anyhting in the list until you further test it.

Comment: Agreed, But here the problem is List of Available comports itself is not Updating, then comes the part whether the port is free or is being owned by some Application!